# Chart.js: Create custom major ticks on log x-Axis?

Tags: chart.js

I cannot figure out how to set custom major ticks on a logarithmic x-Axis on charts.js

In my example, I want ticks on x={0.1, 0.2, 0.315, 0.4, 0.63}, but so far it only works with 0.1, 0.2, 0.4 but not with 0.315 or 0.63.

Here is some code, regarding the xAxis formatting:

```
    options: {
    scales: {
        xAxes: [{
            type: 'logarithmic',
            ticks: {
                min: 0.09,
                max: 4,
                padding: 10,
                minRotation: 90,
                callback: function (value, index, values) {
                    if( value==0.100) {
                        return "0.100";
                        };
                    if(value==0.200) {
                        return "0.200";
                        };
                    if(value==0.315) {
                        return "0.315";
                        };
                    if(value==0.4) {
                        return "0.400";
                        };
                    if(value==0.63) {
                        return "0.630";
                        }
                    }
```

And this is what it looks like:
[Image of my Graph with incorrect ticks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TZ8Bw.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I have found my solution. In addition to defining my ticks (as in the code example above [inside the "callback" function]) I had to alter my ticks afterwards like this:

```
   [...]
   if(value==0.63) {
        return "0.630";
        }
      } //closing bracket from "callback: function"  
    }, //closing bracket from "ticks" section

    //new code that did the trick
    afterBuildTicks: function(pckBarChart) {    
            pckBarChart.ticks = [];
            pckBarChart.ticks.push(0.1);
            pckBarChart.ticks.push(0.2);
            pckBarChart.ticks.push(0.315);
            pckBarChart.ticks.push(0.4);                        
            pckBarChart.ticks.push(0.63);
    }
```

I found this here:
[StackOverflow: chart.js not allowing y axis steps with logarithmic scale](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40183188/chart-js-not-allowing-y-axis-steps-with-logarithmic-scale)